# how to add a jQuery slider into Joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla

I can add basic elements of jQuery into Joomla content such as buttons and such but not a slider.  I'm using an extension that allows me to add javascript right into content.  I know Joomla loads jQuery already but I need to know how to add the slider widget either into the core files or load them into the content file I'm working on so I can call it using this:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

I tried to load a complete JUI file like this but not working:

```
    {source}
[[script type="text/css" src="voa_scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.css"]][[/script]]
[[script type="text/javascript" src="voa_scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"]][[/script]]

    [[script]]
      jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( "#slider" ).slider();
      });
    [[/script]]
    {/source}
```

Do I need to replace the core jQuery file in Joomla with one that has the slider in it?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting the slider extension from? If your expecting it to exist in core jQuery, it does not and you will need to include jQueryUI lib in your code https://jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: yes, I think I need to compile a new library and reference it in the code. working on that now.  only issue is that this is not a Joomla component I'm working on but instead I'm trying to add this directly into Joomla content using Sourcerer.